# Selenium ComparisonFailure between 2 value

Tags: java, selenium, testing

This is the code:

```
    List<WebElement> ProductPrices1 = driver.findElements(By.className("prc-slg"));
    String text1Price = ProductPrices1.get(0).getText();
    
    thread(1500);
    element(ClickBucket).click();
    thread(1500);

    
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'pb-basket-item-price')]"));
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        str = element.getText();

        int cntTL = (str.length() - str.replace("TL", "").length()) / 2;
        if (2 == cntTL) {
            str = str.split("TL")[1].replace("\"", "") + " TL";
        }
      
    }
    
    System.out.println("first value : "+text1Price+"Bucket Value : "+str);
     Assert.assertEquals(text1Price,str);
```

This is the result: 
first value : 1.189 TL Bucket Value : 
1.189  TL
basarisiz
FAILED: signInTestCase
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[1.189] TL> but was:<[
1.189 ] TL>

Comment: There is a space in second value (str) after 1.189, remove that. Give the value of str so I can check.

Comment: first value : 1.699 TLBucket Value : 
1.278 TL
basarisiz
FAILED: signInTestCase
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[1.699] TL> but was:<[
1.278] TL>

Comment: basarisiz means failed in Turkish by the way

Comment: I mean the value captured here : str = element.getText();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve the problem. One of them is:

```java
Assert.assertEquals(text1Price.replace("TL", "").trim(), str.replace("TL", "").trim());
```

Comment: By the way this error only occured when product has discount.

Comment: @BatuhanBakar I think this will work whether product has discount or not.